# Is there a way to query size of source files when downloading from Debian?

Tags: debian, apt, package-management, source

When we run `apt`, `apt-get` or `aptitude` we always know how much space would be needed in `/` and it's children (excepting `/home/$username` of course) .

Now when we do an `apt-get source` (in userspace) there is no way to know the size of source files before downloading them so as not run into any last minute surprises.

I would share a real example to describe the issue.

The binary unknown-horizons is approximately 305 MB uncompressed -

```
[$] aptitude show unknown-horizons

Package: unknown-horizons                
Version: 2014.1+git160920-1
State: installed
Automatically installed: no
Priority: optional
Section: games
Maintainer: Debian Games Team <pkg-games-devel@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Architecture: all
Uncompressed Size: 305 M
Depends: ttf-unifont, python, python-enet, python-fife (>= 0.3.5+git160920), python-yaml, python:any (< 2.8), python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
Description: 2D realtime strategy simulation
 Unknown Horizons is a 2D realtime strategy simulation with an emphasis on economy and city building. Expand your small settlement to a strong
 and wealthy colony, collect taxes and supply your inhabitants with valuable goods. Increase your power with a well balanced economy and with
 strategic trade and diplomacy.
Homepage: http://www.unknown-horizons.org
```

Now if I were to download the source, it either would be downloading the whole 305 MB or more uncompressed packages or just the `/debian` directory which would hardly be an MB or more. Is there a way to do that ?

I am guessing it either would need metadata like `apt-file` does -

```
$ sudo apt-file update
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find out the size of the source tarballs using `apt-cache showsrc`:

```
$ apt-cache showsrc unknown-horizons
Package: unknown-horizons
Binary: unknown-horizons
Version: 2014.1+git160920-1
Maintainer: Debian Games Team <pkg-games-devel@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Uploaders: Christoph Egger <christoph@debian.org>
Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 10), dh-python, docbook-xml, docbook-xsl, imagemagick, intltool, python, xsltproc
Architecture: all
Standards-Version: 3.9.8
Format: 3.0 (quilt)
Files:
 152652f8ecb6961a5f02d3cab67b8cfa 2290 unknown-horizons_2014.1+git160920-1.dsc
 bec6e49f621f3f961454cf41c7e13346 197217496 unknown-horizons_2014.1+git160920.orig.tar.xz
 dccaafd51d0fbe3aaebe874715bc1d93 12512 unknown-horizons_2014.1+git160920-1.debian.tar.xz
Vcs-Browser: https://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/pkg-games/unknown-horizons.git
Vcs-Git: https://anonscm.debian.org/git/pkg-games/unknown-horizons.git
Checksums-Sha256:
 af9fc7592567b75fa84189ca4e823df103e74fcb51e3fe34ea1162a53d08434d 2290 unknown-horizons_2014.1+git160920-1.dsc
 9342154d2ede6e152175c1c69d84f3a51ba2704a77a286103590da40f0d02482 197217496 unknown-horizons_2014.1+git160920.orig.tar.xz
 c6db7500f4dfe4a544ae660f92dd9acdc8248ecdc798a45d4bce0be6992d8a6f 12512 unknown-horizons_2014.1+git160920-1.debian.tar.xz
Homepage: http://www.unknown-horizons.org
Package-List: 
 unknown-horizons deb games optional arch=all
Directory: pool/main/u/unknown-horizons
Priority: source
Section: games
```

Note the `Files:` entries: the `.orig` tarball (containing the upstream source) is 188MiB in size, the `.debian` tarball 12KiB. This doesn't tell you how much space is needed to extract the tarballs, but it gives some indication.

You *can* download only the `debian` directory by only downloading the `.debian` tarball, either from the [source package's page](https://packages.debian.org/source/unstable/unknown-horizons), or using `apt-get source --diff-only`.